# Does the DMA tool support an online migration for on-prem source and on-prem target?

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

I a planning to use the DMA tool to make a test migration from an on-prem source sql server to an on-prem target sql target.

This test will be performed during less busy hours, but there will be users using the source server dbs. Does the DMA tool support an online migration? By online I mean that the source db can be used while the migration is happening.

If yes, then will the migration target contain data as of the start of DMA tool migration process or the end of the migration process?

Answer (score 2):

> By online I mean that the source db can be used while the migration is happening.

Yes it would be accessible but make sure you do not do any write operation on it during migration. Read operation would be fine. This is because internally DMA would take backup of database and logs to migrate your database so basically its backup and restore job working hence database would be accessible.

I would also add DMA does not migrate jobs and other server objects so be careful. I would prefer logshipping or mirroring or Availability groups for migrating to on-premise.

Comment: I have 30 databases and the VM backup tool takes its own log backups so I cannot configure log shipping. Since I use standard license I would have to configure AG per database. Again, since number of db is large I don't want to setup mirroring individually. Hence my decision to go for DMA. I will migrate the SQLs, linked servers separately. Since DMA is based on backup/restore, that means the target will have data as of the time when the backup finished. I just wanted re-assurance that my source db users will not be blocked from doing read/writes.

Comment: I would not suggest to do writes during migration using DMA. Please take downtime window it would be better. Since you have VM and if you can afford some downtime VM snapshot could be taken and then from same snapshot on destination new VM can be built.  Rest I believe your approach is fine if you dont want to go into hassle of LS, Mirroring and AG.

Comment: May I ask you to elaborate on `then from same snapshot on destination new VM can be built`. Do you mean to upgrade the destination in-place? Or do you mean to run the DMA tool on it? Either ways, there are sql jobs scheduled to run every few minures so won't the snapshot cause my jobs to get triggered twice (once on primary and then also on the copy) thereby resulting in a mess because the jobs read/write using linked servers? Or is there a way to isolate the VM so jobs won't have any effect?

Comment: Just ask your VM team that how can they move complete VM from current ESXi host to new host residing in your destination environment, you will get better answer. If you have jobs running every minute I strongly suggest to pause the jobs and then stop agent before doing any migration.